# FB sharing multiple url at single post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, fbsdk

I know the way how to post single link to `FB`

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(url))
                .setQuote(text)
                .build();
        shareDialog.show(linkContent);
    }
```

and it works fine, but I need to share multiple links + link name. Is it possible?

what I've tried:

1) pass data via share intent - text not supported, only url

2) `ShareOpenGraphObject + ShareOpenGraphAction + ShareOpenGraphContent` - looks costume object not supported from 2017? tried  several samples - seems not working

3) creates dialog with generated message (links and text) then `GraphRequest -> "/me/feed" -> HttpMethod.POST` works for test user. but FB denied `publis_actions` request because of "app shouldn't generate message, user should add text by himself"...

some more ideas?

Comment: Not possible. You can share one link at a time, and that is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is very strict when it comes to posting. Using their SDK you can share **1 link per post**, if you want multiple links - you'll need to make multiple posts.

It is possible to post multiple links with the **Graph API**, but you'll need permission from FB, and since you don't have it I guess you are out of luck.

Comment: Do you have link for this in official documentation ?